# How can i pass define (#define SOME_DEFINE) as parameter of the function?

Tags: c++

Well, I was experimented with language features, and didn't find the way, how can I pass define to the function as param. 
I know, that it's not the best practice, just pure interest.

I've already tried to do it in several ways, at least generics didn't help.

So, what I'd like to do is:

```
#define SOME_DEFINE

template <class T>
void foo(T param)
{
    if(param == SOME_DEFINE) do stuff
}

int main
{
    foo(SOME_DEFINE);
}
```

Appreciate you.

Comment: `SOME_DEFINE` evaluates to nothing after preprocessing.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've asked the preprocessor to replace any occurrence of the token `SOME_DEFINE` by nothing, so `foo(SOME_DEFINE);` is compiled as if it were `foo();`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: It doesn't sounds right, as predefine happens compile time, but your code runs dynamically.

Comment: If you want to control your code at the compile time, here is what is looks like.
#define SOME_DEFINE 1
...
#if SOME_DEFINE = 1
//do something
#else
//do something else
#endif
but, only one part of code will be compiled.

Comment: `#define SOME_DEFINE 3` will make this code compile and run (aside from the "do stuff" note).

Comment: Yes, I relized my mistake, thank you, guys.

Comment: The preprocessor is a compile-time only feature. It even expands macros before actual parsing of the code happens.

Comment: Prefer using proper variables over preprocessor macros.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes, i know, thx. just wanted to try some with macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that's missing is a value to your definition.

Just add it and you can start testing the feature.

```
#include <iostream>

#define SOME_DEFINE 42

void do_all_the_things() {
  std::cout << "woohoo!" << std::endl;
}

void do_none_of_the_things() {
  std::cout << "darn" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void foo(T param) {
  if (param == SOME_DEFINE) {
    do_all_the_things();
  } else {
    do_none_of_the_things();
  }
}

int main() {
  foo(42);
  foo(3);
  return 0;
}
```

For strings, it gets a tad bit more complicated.
String literals, `const char*` can't be compared very easily.
For example:

```
const char* a = "value a";
const char* b = "value b";
return a == b;
```

May seem like it works, but it's actually just comparing the pointers and not the content. You could fix this by either defining your macro as `std::string("an example value")` or using a specialized compare function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define SOME_DEFINE "test value"

void do_all_the_things() {
  std::cout << "woohoo!" << std::endl;
}

void do_none_of_the_things() {
  std::cout << "dang it" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
struct AreEqual final {
  bool operator () (T a, T b) const {
    return a == b;
  }
};

template <>
struct AreEqual<const char*> final {
  bool operator () (const char* a, const char* b) const {
    return std::strcmp(a, b) == 0;
  }
};

template <class T, class AreEqualTo = AreEqual<T>>
void foo(T param, AreEqualTo are_equal_to = AreEqualTo()) {
  if (are_equal_to(param, SOME_DEFINE)) {
    do_all_the_things();
  } else {
    do_none_of_the_things();
  }
}

int main() {
  foo("test");
  foo("test value");
  return 0;
}
```

This is another worthy route to explore if you're learning the language. There are a lot of functions in the C++ library that use template functions.

Comment: @LexMarchenko sure thing! I added a section to read if you plan on setting your definitions as strings.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to do the same with strings, but I've never used defines a lot, so, that was a bit of misunderstanding of how it works.